# Custom sorting DevExpress PivotGrid for a column whose PivotGroupInterval is custom

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a PivotGrid that has the following

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         pivotGrid.RetrieveFields();
         pivotGrid.Fields["YEAR"].Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
         pivotGrid.Fields["YEAR"].GroupInterval = PivotGroupInterval.DateYear;
         pivotGrid.Fields["MONTH"].Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
         pivotGrid.Fields["MONTH"].GroupInterval = PivotGroupInterval.Custom;
    }
private void pivotGrid_CustomGroupInterval(object sender, PivotCustomGroupIntervalEventArgs e)
   {
         e.GroupValue = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString("MMM");
   }
```

So my output shows as 
[image]
Note that the  months are sorted by name of month and not the underlying date. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out the answer myself

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         pivotGrid.RetrieveFields();
         pivotGrid.Fields["YEAR"].Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
         pivotGrid.Fields["YEAR"].GroupInterval = PivotGroupInterval.DateYear;
         pivotGrid.Fields["MONTH"].Area = PivotArea.ColumnArea;
         pivotGrid.Fields["MONTH"].GroupInterval = PivotGroupInterval.Custom;
         pivotGrid.Fields["MONTH"].SortMode = PivotSortMode.Custom;
    }
private void pivotGrid_CustomGroupInterval(object sender, PivotCustomGroupIntervalEventArgs e)
   {
         e.GroupValue = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString("MMM");
   }
private void pivotGrid_CustomFieldSort(object sender, PivotGridCustomFieldSortEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Field.FieldName == "MONTH")
    {
                if (e.Value1 == null || e.Value2 == null) return;
                e.Handled = true;
                DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime("1 " + e.Value1.ToString() + " 1900");
                DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime("1 " + e.Value2.ToString() + " 1900");
                if (d1 > d2)
                    e.Result = 1;
                else if (d1 == d2)
                    e.Result = 0;
                else
                    e.Result = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the same issue but your solution solved it Thanks :)